# Dificuldade de Abstração em Casos de Uso

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Estou começando a estudar Casos de Uso e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dificuldade de abstração:** Confundo muitas vezes ao criar vários casos de uso mas que na verdade
precisaria somente de um, pois esse representaria todos. Existem algumas dicas para que se possa saber sobre o que é e o que não é um caso de uso? No exemplo acima, o caso de uso "3. Efetuar Pagamento" faria parte do caso de uso "2. Fazer Pedido"? Caso faça parte, os detalhes em relação
às formas de pagamento (casos de uso 4,5 e 6) deveria estar na especificação do caso de uso "2. Fazer Pedido" demonstrando o passo-a-passo?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: "No exemplo acima, o caso de uso "3. Efetuar Pagamento" faria parte do caso de uso "2. Fazer Pedido"?"
Raphael, acredito que sim, visto que seria necessário sempre realizar um pedido antes de pagá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Existem algumas dicas para que se possa saber sobre o que é e o que não é um caso de uso?**

Caso de uso são usados para identificar e registrar os requisitos funcionais do sistema. Os Diagramas de casos de uso auxiliam a comunicação entre os analistas e o sistema, descrevendo o cenário com as funcionalidades.

O diagrama de Caso de Uso é representado por:

- atores;
- casos de uso;
- relacionamentos entre estes elementos.

Estes relacionamentos podem ser:

- associações entre atores e casos de uso;
- generalizações entre os atores;
- generalizações, `extends` e `includes` entre os casos de uso.

**No exemplo acima, o caso de uso "3. Efetuar Pagamento" faria parte do caso de uso "2. Fazer Pedido"?**

No seu diagrama, 3 faz parte de 2. Está certo o `include`. É para isso que ele serve.

Para você entender melhor, no [site da UFCG](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~sampaio/cursos/2007.1/Graduacao/SI-II/Uml/diagramas/usecases/usecases.htm) tem essa explicação:

> - **Include**: Um relacionamento `include` de um caso de uso A para um caso de uso B indica que B é essencial para o comportamento de A.
>     Pode ser dito também que B is_part_of A.
> - **Extend**: Um relacionamento `extend` de um caso de uso B para um caso de uso A indica que o caso de uso B pode ser acrescentado para
>     descrever o comportamento de A (não é essencial). A extensão é
>     inserida em um ponto de extensão do caso de uso A. Ponto de extensão
>     em um caso de uso é uma indicação de que outros casos de uso poderão
>     ser adicionados a ele. Quando o caso de uso for invocado, ele
>     verificará se suas extensões devem ou não serem invocadas. Quando se
>     especifica B `extends` A, a semântica é:
>
>   - Dois casos de uso são definidos: A e A extended by B;
>   - B é uma variação de A. Contém eventos adicionais, para certas condições;
>   - Tem que ser especificado onde B é inserido em A.

**Utilidade do caso de uso**

Apesar de simples eles são úteis desde a comunicação com o cliente até a geração dos casos de testes. Isso porque,não exigem conhecimento técnico e o cliente pode entender o diagrama sem esforço. Além disso, novos casos de usos geram novos requisitos e a junção de todos os cenários são usadas para sugerir os testes para cada cenário.

Referências:

- [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_de_uso)
- [O que é UML e Diagramas de Caso de Uso](http://www.devmedia.com.br/o-que-e-uml-e-diagramas-de-caso-de-uso-introducao-pratica-a-uml/23408)
- [Casos de uso](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~sampaio/cursos/2007.1/Graduacao/SI-II/Uml/diagramas/usecases/usecases.htm)