# Dúvida na Representação de Casos de Uso

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Do link [Dificuldade de Abstração em Casos de Uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146583/dificuldade-de-abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-casos-de-uso), fiz a seguinte interpretação:

"Somente o atendente poderá confirmar o envio do pedido, mas para isso é necessário ter a finalização do pedido, que somente poderá ser feita pelo pizzaiolo. Mas para finalizar um
pedido é necessário que o cliente efetue o pagamento e por sua vez é necessário fazer o
pedido pelo mesmo".
Essa leitura que está representada no diagrama está correta?
Caso esteja correta, isso me confunde muito pois a função do Diagrama de Casos de Uso
é representar os objetivos de cada ator, e não deve-se representar esses objetivos
numa sequência de passos a serem feitas como no Diagrama de Atividades, mas podemos perceber nesse
exemplo que há um fluxo a ser seguido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O diagrama documenta o que o sistema faz do ponto de vista de um usuário. Ele descreve as principais funcionalidades do sistema e a interação dessas funcionalidades com os usuários do mesmo sistema. Nesse tipo de diagrama não é preciso se aprofundar nos detalhes técnicos que dizem como o sistema faz as ações(Linguagem, SGBD etc).

Nesse caso, está representado tudo que o Usuário Cliente pode fazer, que é se cadastrar, fazer pedido e pagar. O usuário Atendente pode apenas confirmar o Envio do pedido. O Usuário Pizzaiolo, pode consultar pedido e finalizar pedido.

Estão representados todo o fluxo do sistema, mas também as ações de cada ator, podendo ser analisadas tanto individualmente, quanto em conjunto,então está correta a representação. O diagrama de atividades é diferente deste, porquê possui incluído uma lógica para representar o fluxo das atividades, costuma ser mais próximo a um algoritmo.

Em Resumo: Diagrama de Caso de uso é uma representação na Visão de um usuário do Sistema, com explicações simples e sem detalhamento técnico. Diagrama de Atividades, é uma representação do fluxo, contendo lógica, próximo a uma representação algorítmica do sistema.